# Order by ou filtro em join Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

É possível utilizar order by ou algum filtro em inner join ou left join ou estou tentando fazer isso de forma errada.
Eu preciso trazer em uma consulta uma coluna que está em uma tabela filha, mas eu preciso que seja a coluna do registro mais recente dos registros da tabela filha.
Para resolver esse problema eu fiz um sub-query e resolveu bem o problema, mas eu queria saber se teria como fazer um join com top 1 e ordenado por uma coluna.

Comment: Poderia postar o que você já fez?

Comment: ... e o perguntador some ...

Answer (score 0):

Abaixo tem um script de como fazer o que gostaria, porem se conseguir postar o que fez para entender melhor ficará mais claro para todos.

```
Select TOP 10 TB1.COLUNANOVA 
from Tabela1 TB1
   inner join Tabela2 TB2
      on TB1.CODPRIMARIO = TB2.CODIGOPRIMARIO
where TB1.COLUNAANTIGA = "resultado"
order by TB1.COLUNANOVA
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você quer não pode ser resolvido com *Cross Apply*? Segue um exemplo de uso, só não está ordenando, mas aí você edita para o que se aplica ao seu caso.

```
SELECT  Employee.EmployeeId ,
        FirstName ,
        LastName ,
        PhoneType ,
        PhoneNumber
FROM    dbo.Employee
        CROSS  APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                PhoneNumber ,
                                PhoneType ,
                                EmployeeId
                      FROM      dbo.PhoneNumber
                      WHERE     PhoneType = 4
                                AND EmployeeId = Employee.EmployeeId ) p
ORDER BY EmployeeId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia!

Acredito que poderia fazer assim também, ou seja, colocar um TOP 1 em um select como se fosse uma coluna, com o where = a coluna de fora. Sendo assim vai trazer o último registro de cada item consultado.

```
Select 

CT1.coluna_1_tabela_1,
(select TOP 1 CT3.coluna_1_tabela_3 from Tabela3 CT3 where CT3.coluna_1_tabela_3 = CT1.coluna_1_tabela_1 order BY CT3.coluna_1_tabela_3 DESC) as Seu_resultado

from Tabela1 CT1
   INNER JOIN Tabela2 CT2
      on CT1.coluna_1_tabela_1 = CT2.coluna_1_tabela_2
where CT1.coluna_10_tabela1 = 'XYZ'
order by CT1.coluna_1_tabela_1
```